# Swap pdf and source in TeXShop "one window"

Tags: texshop

I am using TeXShop on a Mac and have a wide monitor.  The way I have my desk set up it is more ergonomic to have the source on the right and the pdf on the left, but when I "Use One Window" it defaults to the other way round and I can't see if it is possible to switch them.  Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think this is changeable. But you can use separate windows and set the preference for all windows to start at a fixed position, putting the source on the right.

Comment: Thanks.  I've just realised that I can put two windows next to each other in full screen mode using Split View, so I guess that solves my problem.